# how to take screenshots and paste it in a word /text file oneafter other in selenium rc &webdriver?

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

```
selenium.captureScreenshot("/tmp/" + this.getClass().getName() + "."
+ testMethodName + ".png");
selenium.captureEntirePageScreenShotToString();
selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot("C:\screenshot.png","");
```

I tried all the above but I need some way to paste the screen shots in a text/document page one after other.

Comment: How to take the screenshot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: How to insert image to word/excel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681206/insert-image-into-excel-java

Comment: Thanks Alex .Your suggestions helped .